# Joomla! system plugin to add extra params to all modules

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I need to create a system plugin with one goal - add extra group fields of parameters to all module available.

There's one solution that I know of - into every XML manifest of every module add extra parameters, but this is bad solution for two reason:

1) It make impossible to update the modules without loosing these
    changes
2) Its is lot of work
3) It makes extending of these
    parameters almost impossible

**What I want to do:**

I want to make a systems plugin, that adds to every installed module a group of parameters.

**What I am asking for:**

I looked through the internet for a solution. I found out that I don't need to create new type of parameter. I want to use built-in type - text or list.

There is some tutorials, which have info about adding parameters to a single module and retrieving them for this single module `helper.php`. Yes, that's the thing I don't want too.

I asking for a link to bunch of tutorials or advice how to proceed further without tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

this module is using what you are searching for. If you have time you may analise it and maybe you'll find answer.
[Advanced module manager](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Extract it from different component of module is very time consuming and not clearafing as i want the advice to be :-) If someone will find a documentation link, i will be happy :-)  Jonuxx Thank you.